# How to add text boxes dynamically when one text box is filled?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, textbox

I have text box to fill the ph.numbers in that, here what i want is, whenever i'm entering the value in that text box i need to add another empty text box dynamically where i can add another value in that in the same way if they are entering any value into this new empty box another empty text box should add at the bottom of this. And after all there is a confirm link button. When clicking on it all these ph.numbers entering on the text boxes should get. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You add textboxes dynamically using jquery and on the button click/submit there values to the server. What you can do is on keyup event of a textbox you can add another below it.

Comment: I agree with this. The other answer is, imo, bogus, since it tries to use server side code to edit client side controls... Which does work and is normal in ASP.NET, but not like this...

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

I'm basing this condition that your number format is of 11, Ex: 09123456789

So on the Textbox_Textchanged event of your textbox.

```
if(textbox.text.length >= 11)
{
    Textbox text = new Textbox();
    text.TextChanged += Textbox_Textchanged; // So it would also trigger the event
    // Do positioning here
}
```

Im thinking you can better optimize this by having a better EventArgs but you get the idea right?

Comment: ohh sorry ..ph.num is just for an exaple. actually i want to insert nvarchar values on text box  @Ronald Estacion

Comment: You sure? That is a WebForms application, you can't really just... listen to an Textchanged without using ajax or anything... It would PostBack the whole damn page for each key (if it would even do that!) Even if this solution worked, @ARATHY, it wouldnt be different with strings

Comment: @sinni800 he was asking how to create textbox's dynamically, how not to postback. arathy, Just build up a condition that'll trigger the event, you can replace the EventArgs of it and supply your own property, a method will work too.

Comment: @RonaldEstacion Creating a textbox will need a postback. It will not magically appear on the web page